# Permission denied after using setfacl

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions, permission-denied

There are 3 users: A, B, C.

**A** has mydir in his home folder `/home/A/mydir`

**B** can read `/home/A` contents

**C** can read and write `/home/A` contents

I tried in this way:

```
setfacl -Rm u:B:r /home/A/
setfacl -Rm u:C:rw /home/A/

su B
ls /home/A
ls: cannot access /home/A: Permission denied
mydir
cd /home/A
-bash: cd: /home/A/: Permission denied
```

---

cat /etc/fstabs:

> /dev/sdb1       /media/esterno  ext3    defaults,acl    0       2

---

getfacl /home/A:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/A
# owner: A
# group: A
user::rwx
user:B:r--
user:C:rw-
group::---
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Comment: Normally you would want setfacl to recalculate the mask. Can you print the output of `getfacl /home/A`.

Comment: i updated the main post

Comment: I see the issue. You need to give both B and C execute permission. Directories even when readable or writable will not allow going into when execute permission is not set.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! 

But where is the logic? Why should i set execute permission if i'm reading it?

Comment: You need the execution permission to open a directory on a unix system...

Comment: You were not just reading it, you were traversing it. Traversing a directory requires an execute permission.

Answer (score 10):

As [tampis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1165155/tampis) allready said, to change into a directory (or list its content, or read a file in it) in linux, one needs to have execute permissions on that directory.
Change your `setfacl` commad to something like this:

```
setfacl -Rm u:B:rx /home/A/
setfacl -Rm u:C:rwx /home/A/
```

Comment: this is nuts. 

`sudo setfacl -Rm u:user1:rx /x/x/`

`cd /x/x/`

Permission denied

Comment: So does this only work because the home dir is already executable by B and C? What if you first did [root]> setfacl -Rm u:C:rwx /home/A/shared/ then [C]> cd /home/A/shared? Is it true that every parent dir needs x permissions, to traverse?

Comment: yes, every directory in the path needs to have the executable bit set to be able to `cd` into a sub folder.

Answer (score 1):

you also need  execute permission along with read permission on directory

```
"setfacl -m  u:B:r-x /home/A"
```